# Java: Getting Exception while sending attachment email

Tags: java, email, exception, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm getting runtime exception `UnsupportedDataTypeException` while sending an email in java. Here is the exception in detail

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_764977973.1480687764115"
```

How can I tackle this exception?

I'm using this piece of code: complete code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String senderMail = "inzi769@gmail.com";
    String recepMail = "inzi.programmer@gmail.com";
    String pass = "*********";
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Inzimam\\Desktop\\helicopter_final.png";

    sendJavaMail(senderMail, pass, recepMail, host, filePath);
}

private static void sendJavaMail(String senderMail, String pass, String recepMail, String host, String filePath) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    // Get the Session object.
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(senderMail, pass);
                }
            });
    session.setDebug(true);
    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);            
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderMail));            
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recepMail));            
        message.setSubject("Subject here");            
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();            
        messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");            
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();            
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);            
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();


        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filePath);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);            
        message.setContent(multipart); 
        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");
        t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", senderMail, pass);
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();
//           Transport.send(message);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message has been sent  successfully!.");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Please point out that where I'm wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to overwrite your the variable messageBodyPart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I was using [Javamail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) 1.4.6 But Now with the Javamail API [Version 1.5.0](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxmail150jar.htm) or higher the same code above is working correctly. So, now with API 1.5.0 I'm able to send attachment successfully.

**Edit:** with API 1.4.6 when I used

```
Transport.send(message);
```

it did not work But with API 1.5.0 or higher we can also use

```
Transport.send(message);
```

instead of

```
SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");
            t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", senderMail, pass);
            t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            t.close();
```

Comment: Note that the [current version is JavaMail 1.5.6](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: @BillShannon yes now I'm using it.